# Why won't geopy run?

Tags: python

I have anaconda 3, so pip is already installed. Therefore, when I do the install `geopy` in the terminal it all works out fine. However, when I tried to run the example code given [here](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy-2-0), an error pops up saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopy.geocoders'; 'geopy' is not a package.` I've uninstalled and reinstalled geopy. Nothing seems to help.

Thank you!

Comment: can you please write the whole error code here? how do you install `geopy`?

Comment: because i've installed it, it's working without error

Comment: maybe you have two Pythons and you installed module in one Python but you run example with another Python. Better check `pip -V` and `python -V` to see if you use `pip` to install in module for correct Python. Or use `python -m pip install ...`

Comment: Thank you for the whole responses! So, the error message is this:   File "geopy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
  File "/Users/bs/Desktop/python/geopy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopy.geocoders'; 'geopy' is not a package

Comment: And the versions I'm using are (base) Brennas-MBP:python bs$ pip -V
pip 19.1.1 from /Users/bs/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
(base) Brennas-MBP:python bs$ python -V
Python 3.7.3

Comment: Likewise, I installed it by doing "pip install geopy" in the terminal without being any particular folder or directory, just at the "base"

Comment: Do `$ which pip` to make sure the `pip` executable you're using is indeed the one from your `conda` environment. Afterwards, you should also check that `geopy` is installed by your `pip` with `$ pip list`